# TextProperty field in NDB gets "=" appended after every line

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have very strange case which I wasn't able to debug for a day.

On my front-end I have form with textarea and submit button. 
On submission, the textarea field gets saved as `ndb.TextProperty()`
When I submit a multiline text, the text in the database gets `=` or `=20` characters on every line. At first I thought they get randomly inserted, but it seems every 76 characters gets one `=` character.

This gets really hard to debug as on my localhost instance it works perfectly fine, but on the deployed version it doesn't. They are both in sync. Also on my localhost instance the text field on the datastore entity shows correctly the newline and tab characters, but on the deployed version, the datastore field is shown as one text blob without newlines or tabs.

Anyone can guide me to the right direction ?

Comment: Can you file a production bug on the issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: It looks like a multipart mime form was not used, and you have text padding.  How was your form defined and what browser are you using ?

Comment: Thanks @Tim, that is actually a very correct guess! On the form I also have an input for a file and my enctype __is__ infact `"multipart/form-data"`. Is there a way to have the form handle files and text inputs aswell ?

Comment: Yes, we do it all the time.  You will probably need to show some more details to help you work out what the problem is.  I assume your method is POST and not GET.

Comment: It is a POST method and the form have input for file or text. When the file input is empty the user submits text or vise versa. If I don't set the enctype to  `"multipart/form-data"`, it handles the text properly, but I can't submit files. My Handler on the server side inherits both a `BlobstoreUploadHandler` and a `webapp2.RequestHandler`. Thanks!

Comment: @TimHoffman Do you need more info ? Not sure what to provide, other than that. It is very straight forward application. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, BlobStoreHandler you didn't mention that in your original question.

Ok there is your problem.

I don't believe you can combine the two. If you are uploading to the Blobstore you can't do other form elements, as the upload is directed to the BlobStore service.

From the docs

> The user creates a blob by submitting an HTML form that includes one
>   or more file input fields. Your application calls create_upload_url()
>   to get the destination (action) of this form, passing the function a
>   URL path of a handler in your application. When the user submits the
>   form, the user's browser uploads the specified files directly to the
>   Blobstore. The Blobstore rewrites the user's request and stores the
>   uploaded file data, replacing the uploaded file data with one or more
>   corresponding blob keys, then passes the rewritten request to the
>   handler at the URL path you provided to create_upload_url(). This
>   handler can do additional processing based on the blob key.

So it's difficult to say exactly what is going on without seeing your code, but I seriously doubt you can do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I guess you are right. I will modify my logic to make two separate handlers for files and text input then. Thanks for guiding me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same problem,

I solved it in a way that isn't elegant, but functional:

I did a replace on the input;

here is the code

```
input_html_text = unicode(self.request.get('text')).replace('=\r\n', '')
```