# google app engine ndb adding = after about every 12 words

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have no idea why this is happening and have no clue how to fix it. I was wondering if anyone had the same issue. I'm using a WYSIWYG HTML editor and sending text to my database `ndb.TextProperty(required=False)`. The problem is not with localhost, but with my actual website. When I upload sample text I get random equals signs!!!

Example 1

`Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero i= n 45 BC
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit volupta= tem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae a= b illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt expl= icabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut= fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequ= i nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet= , consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incid= unt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minim= a veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, n= isi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehend= erit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel i= llum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"`

Example 2 (held down "a" for approx 15 seconds

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I found an article where someone had a similar problem. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/cuZrHz3mDZQ

Comment: It will be for incorrect mimetype and your getting padding.  I answered someone elses question on SO who had the same answer.  Just can't find it at the moment.

Comment: thanks Tim! From reading the site on my above comment, I think you're right. I'm using (blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler): instead of (webapp2.RequestHandler). It's just weird that it works correctly on localhost but not on google's actual servers

Comment: was this it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207310/textproperty-field-in-ndb-gets-appended-after-every-line/23248467#23248467

Comment: wow, I'm finding more and more good resources. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624226/encoding-problem-in-app-engine-when-submitting-multipart-form-data-forms

Comment: Yep that was question

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this problem, I found this hack on the site of my first comment.

```
#Equal sign hack
messedUpString= messedUpString.encode('utf-8') 
messedUpString= quopri.decodestring(messedUpString)
messedUpString= " ".join(messedUpString.split()) #Remove all whitespaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem,

I solved it in a way that isn't elegant, but it works:

I did a replace on the input;

here is the code

```
input_html_text = unicode(self.request.get('text')).replace('=\r\n', '')
```

**Note:** if you inspect the code, you will find ***after the equal sign there is a carriage return***; this, always happen when you're using a *"multipart/form-data"* with *BlobstoreUploadHandler* and, in my case, *webapp2.RequestHandler*.

I hope that can be helpful.